# Why do I need to async/await again in a different function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm confused of why do I need to run the async/await again in another function

Example

```
async function fetchData() {
   try {
        const result = await axios.get('http://example.com')
        return result

    } catch(err) {
       return err

     }
}


// and in another function I need to async await again 

// if I want to get the value of fetchData() 

// or else it will return pending promise object


function mapData() {
     const data = fetchData()
     console.log(data) // is a Pending Promise    
}
```

If I want to get the data instead of Promise object

```
async function mapData() {
     const data = await fetchData() // I still need to await?? 
     console.log(data) // real value
}
```

I thought that If I already async/await in `fetchData` function it's already return a value instead of promise, why do I need to async/await again to get the actual data in `mapData` function?

Comment: An async function *always* returns a promise, you can't magically make it synchronous.

Comment: Using `.then()` is a more ideal option here.

Comment: You can remove the `async/await` from `fetchData` it's unnecessary there, since `axios` returns a promise

Comment: `axios.get('http://example.com').then(function(data){ console.log(data); })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `async` function will always return a Promise - a Promise that resolves once the async function reaches its end (after any possible containing `await`s). It doesn't magically make asynchronous code synchronous; any consumers of an async function will have to deal with its asynchronity as well.

It also usually makes more sense to handle errors in the *consumer*. Here, it doesn't look like you're doing anything special with the error in `fetchData`, so you can return the Promise immediately, without having to `await` it in the downstream function:

```
function fetchData() {
   return axios.get('http://example.com');
}
async function mapData() {
     try {
       const data = await fetchData()
       console.log(data)
     } catch(e) {
       console.log('Something went wrong...');
       // handle failure of fetchData
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Promises deal with time. They are a wrapper for a value that will be available eventually, BUT NOT YET. And you don't freeze your entire app untill the value is avilable.

async/await is just syntactic sugar over Promises. It lets you write code like

```
async function myFunction(){
  var id = await asyncMethod1();
  var value = await asyncMethod2(id);
  return syncMethod3(id, value);
}
```

instead of

```
function myFunction(){
  return asyncMethod1().then(id => asyncMethod2(id).then(value => syncMethod3(id, value)));
}
```

but it doesn't change how this thing works underneath.

So although `syncMethod3` is sync the returned value still relies on the asyncronously computed  values `foo` and `bar`. which makes `myfunction` async.

And every function that calls `myFunction` needs to wait untill `myFunction` has computed its value, ... and so on.